# SVN create new branch - old code

Tags: php, svn

I have to develop new version on an old code, however I would need access to old one after commit. Is there a way to handle it in SVN?

Changes are huge almost every file. I was thinking to create a new repository and import new version there.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Highly recommend to try Hg/Git for most workflows... YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a branch: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html.